# Validator fails for not required integer field in laravel 5.3 when I use $request->only()

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3

$request->all() in laravel returns only passed params.

Example:

```
array:1 [
  "user" => array:2 [
  "phone" => "+7(900)900-10"
  "password" => "123"
 ]
]
```

But when I use $request->only(["field1", "field2", ...]) it returns

```
array:1 [
  "user" => array:6 [
     "phone" => "+7(900)900-10"
     "password" => "123"
     "first_name" => null
     "last_name" => null
     "middle_name" => null
     "manager_id" => null
      ]
    ]
```

And validation fails for field `manager_id` which has these rules: `"integer", "min:1"`

This field is nullable in database and when not passed from browser it must be set to null.

How to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do anything, Laravel will create a row and `manager_id` will be `null`.

To make validation pass, try to remove the `required` rule if you're using it or use the [`sometimes`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#conditionally-adding-rules) rule.

> In some situations, you may wish to run validation checks against a field only if that field is present in the input array. To quickly accomplish this, add the sometimes rule to your rule list:

```
'email' => 'sometimes|required|email'
```

Comment: There is no `required` rule on this field.